# How to print counter using flush in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, counter

The following code used to work in Python 2.7 but doesn't seem to work in Python 3.7 jupyter notebook.

```
import sys
import time
for i in range(100):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Python: 3.7.3 Jupyter-Lab: 0.35.4

Instead of printing all numbers I would like to print, clear and print again.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "doesn't seem to work"? I am not seeing any issues with Python 3.7.2 and Jupyter 4.4.0

Comment: In python 2.7, it just prints the number, clears it and replaces the number with next number until the end of the loop. But in Python 3.7, it prints all the numbers without clearing the previous number.

Comment: I'm getting the same undesired behavior in both Python 3.7 and Python 2.7. It may be due to changes in Jupyter Notebook. What version are you using? I'm using Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4.

Comment: I don't remember the jupyter version when I used this code with Python 2.7 two years ago. I am currently using Jupyter-lab not jupyter notebook but it doesn't make any difference as I tried in jupyter notebook and getting the same result. Nevertheless, is there any other way to achieve the intended  behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to achieve the desired behavior in both Python 2.7 and 3.7 kernels. The `'\r'` is necessary. I tried `'\n'` and that prints a number on a new line.

```
import sys
import time

for i in range (100):  
    sys.stdout.write(f"\r{str(i)}")
    time.sleep(1)
```